# Database doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, syntax-error

I use sql server 2014 and with following piece of code:

```
if db_id('handel') is not null
    drop database handel;

create database handel;
use handel;
```

I get the error: `Database 'handel' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.` on line `use handel`, which blows my mind a bit, as just a line before I create said database. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed GO Keyword:

```
if db_id('handel') is not null
    drop database handel;

create database handel;
GO
use handel;
```